# Why can't I bundle update the latest "released" rails 3.2.16 gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Its important to update rails after all of the security fixes, but when I try it says the gem does not exist even though the rails blog says it has been released.

The blog says to upgrade: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/1/28/Rails-3-0-20-and-2-3-16-have-been-released/

But when I add the following to the Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.16'
```

And when I update I get:

```
➜ bundle update rails                                                                                                                                                                                   (ruby-1.9.3-p374@usertesting-orders) 
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/......
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Could not find gem 'rails (= 3.2.16) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

Any tips?

UPDATE: there is no such gem. Its supposed to be 3.2.11 NOT 3.2.16. The .16 is for the 2.3 Rails and not the 3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `gem 'rails', '3.2.11'` ,according to the [stable branch in GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/RAILS_VERSION).

Comment: This is the newest stable version. Fix your Gemfile, then run `bundle update rails`.